# Different bullet images for unordered list in html/css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add different images as bullets to an unordered list? If so how? My code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="chat.html">Chat</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

Comment: This question belongs to Google

Comment: And yes it is possible.

Comment: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+it+possible+to+add+different+images+as+bullets+to+an+unordered+list&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS562US562&oq=Is+it+possible+to+add+different+images+as+bullets+to+an+unordered+list&aqs=chrome..69i57.1514j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The only drawback of Google search - first links point to w3schools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
```